# Difference between "the main reason" and "the chief reason"

Tags: meaning, expressions

What's the difference between *"the main reason"* and *"the chief reason"*? I've heard both, but have no idea where exactly these two differ.

Comment: I think the difference lies solely with that between 'main' and 'chief'. Do you have reason to believe otherwise?

Comment: @Mitch - I think the difference between 'main' and 'chief' is way bigger than the difference between 'the main reason' and 'the chief reason'. For example, one of the points of the difference between 'main' and 'chief' would be the fact that the first word ('main') can be used as a part of a term in grammar - 'the main clause', where is the second word ('chief') is never used to form a term in grammar (at least I have never heard such term as 'the chief clause'). This point of difference is not included in the scope of difference between 'the main reason' and 'the chief reason'

Comment: See Barry's answer then. Summary: mostly the same; minor inconsequential variations in context.

Comment: brilliant: the fact that these words can be applied in other contexts (e.g., a _tribal chief_, a _main office_) does not negate the validity of what @Mitch said. To do a comparison, we must extract only the parts of the dictionary definitions which apply to this context. NOAD says _chief_ means "most important", and _main_ means "chief in importance." Hence, you're right, the differences between these two words expand beyond this context – but Mitch is also right: dictionary definitions plainly show that the two can be used interchangably when talking about the most significant reason.

Comment: @J.R. - I am afraid you didn't get the point there. Mitch put forth the idea that "[main reason]≠[chief reason]" difference is fully determined by the "[main]≠[chief]" difference, and I expressed to him my doubts about that idea. In math x-y=(x+5)-(y+5) is correct, but language is not math, therefore x-y is not equal to (x+"reason")-(y+"reason"). I hope you understand what I am trying to say here.

Comment: @J.R. - The essential difference here is that, unlike in math, we are not dealing with numbers, but with words. Two words together form another notion with totally another set of meanings and connotations.In other words, "main"+"reason"≠"main reason".

Comment: @J.R. - "dictionary definitions plainly show that the two can be used interchangably when talking about the most significant reason" - I agree with this. However, there is one important thing that dictionaries rarely/never show - it is in which context the word in question is used more. Two words may be almost identical in their meaning, however, they still can differ in the contexts that they are usually used in. Therefore, I think Barrie's idea to resort to the help of a corpus search is a great idea.

Comment: @brillant: I think Mitch was prodding you to add to your question, explaining WHY you thought, (as you put it), "main"+"reason"≠"main reason". Language may not be math, but it often behaves that way: "yellow"+"bus"="yellow bus", and "shallow"+"question"="shallow question". You may as well have asked: What's the difference between *main point* & *key point*, or *chief difference* & *primary difference*, or *major factor* & *signficant factor*, or *main argument* & *pivotal argument*, or *minor trifle* & *small trifle*. The onus is on you to explain WHY you think these might not be synonymous.

Comment: @J.R. - "yellow"+"bus" does not equal to "yellow bus"! The adjective "yellow", for example, has a meaning of "being scandalous or ordinary" (like in "yellow journalism"). In "yellow bus", however, that connotation is totally gone.

Comment: @J.R. - "The onus is on you to explain WHY you think these might not be synonymous" - J.R, I am afraid you are putting quite a big of a burden on my shoulders here. I am just asking a question. I am already  missing on some basic understanding here. And yet you want me already to be able to explain why I think they are not synonymous. They could be synonymous or could be not - I simply don't know! I am not a native English speaker after all. I know that in my native language I would be a far cry from thinking that they are synonymous, but I really don't have any basis to project it on English.

Comment: @brilliant: As a matter of practice, if you are going to ask a "What is the difference between X & Y?" question, where X and Y are synonymous, I think it's best to provide a relatively thoughtful explanation of why you think there might be a difference, and this should go beyond "because they might not be" or "because language doesn't always work that way."  Otherwise, the board is liable to be peppered with scores of unreasearched questions: "I've heard both X & Y, where do they differ?" (And, please, a yellow bus is a yellow bus ~ reread what I wrote about **context** in my first comment.)

Comment: @J.R. - "And, please, a yellow bus is a yellow bus ~ reread what I wrote about context in my first comment" - Please re-read my very first answer to Mitch. You and I are talking about two different things: you are talking about **one of** the meanings of one particular word, while I am talking about the **scope of** of all possible usual meanings of one particular word. If you are familiar with programming, you are talking about only one element in an array, while I am talking about the whole array.

Comment: All I really wanted to say is that I think your question was hastily written, and that Mitch's comment should have motivated you to improve it, rather than start a lengthy debate in the comments.

Comment: @J.R. - "I think it's best to provide a relatively thoughtful explanation of why you think there might be a difference" - Would this explanation suffice: "because in my language there is a difference between them"? I really have no other explanations. I think we are running here into an old painful problem when a native speaker just can't put himself into the shoes of a non-native speaker, while the non-native speaker feels that being able to formulate his question here properly amounts to simply already being able to answer it by himself.

Comment: @J.R. - "that Mitch's comment should have motivated you to improve it" - well, then Mitch should've told me this in plain words instead of just implying that. I am not a native speaker, so I simply didn't get it in his comment. I took it as a question that he was asking me and, therefore, I began to answer that question.

Comment: Indeed, something along those lines _would_ have sufficed; it would have made your question more interesting, useful, and relevent. As for what you called that "old painful problem," I don't think we hold non-natives to an impossible standard, all we ask is that everyone – native & non-native speakers alike – put forth a good-faith effort, and somehow convey that effort in the question itself. But really, I'm trying to give helpful advice for your next question, not this one. (BTW, I'm tired of seeing gruff "Why the downvote?" comments, and, when I try to explain mine, look what happens!)

Comment: @J.R. - I am quite surprised that those lines would suffice - I thought it would add nothing to my question. Just a little addition: If you ask an average native English speaker what "yellow press" means, he would probably say it means "some printed matter about some scandalous stuff". And if you ask another average English speaker about what "yellow bus" means, he would probably tell you that it means "a certain vehicle of a color of banana for transporting a big number of people" - I am pretty sure he wouldn't say it means (or even could mean) "a scandalous bus" - that's what I meant.

Comment: @brilliant: for the specific question about main/chief/reason, you've gotten the answer multiple times: there is little difference (for this set of words, in the context you specify in the OP, in English). For the general question, you are correct that context matters; synonyms can't always replace others in idioms (and you've given examples like 'yellow'). Back to the specific question, there's nothing really special about main and chief and reason, but 'main' and 'chief' ill appear in different idioms (that's somewhat self-defining of 'idiom').

Comment: @brilliant: (1) such additional information would have shown extra effort and explained why you were confused; both of those are valuable. (2) I never said "yellow"+"press"="yellow press"; I understand your point - I hope you can understand mine.

Answer (score 7):

Why stop with two?  You can also speak of *the prime reason, the central reason, the primary reason, the principle reason, the foremost reason, the predominant reason and the pre-eminent reason.* Like *main* and *chief*, they have much the same meaning, but are likely to be found in different contexts. Only a corpus search can reveal what those contexts might be.

Comment: What is a corpus search?

Comment: @brilliant- corpus search is a search where you search written documents, books, etc. Google Books is one example of corpus search.

Comment: @brilliant: A corpus is a large collection of text stored electronically. It allows an analyst to examine the contexts in which a word is used.